# To get Status Changing Data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Date                           Status            Date_Change 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-07-10-15.05.46.918680       A               2019-07-10-15.05.46.934000
2019-07-10-15.05.46.918680       A               2019-07-10-15.05.50.272680
2019-07-10-15.05.46.918680       A               2019-07-10-15.05.50.491680  
2019-07-10-15.05.46.918680       B               2019-07-10-15.05.50.740680
2019-07-10-15.05.46.918680       B               2019-07-10-15.05.50.990680
2019-07-10-15.05.46.918680       A               2019-07-15-10.44.54.386680
2019-07-10-15.05.46.918680       A               2019-07-15-10.44.54.837680
2019-07-10-15.05.46.918680       A               2019-07-15-10.45.28.769680
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4qTL.png)

Referring to the above data I need data for those Date whose status has changed from A to other like B,C, D etc and again came back to A.

Please help. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have tried

```
select status, min(DATE_CHANGE), max(DATE_CHANGE)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by DATE_CHANGE) -
              row_number() over (partition by status order by DATE_CHANGE)
             ) as grp
      from mytable t
     ) t
group by status, grp
```

but it's not working.

Output should be like :-

```
Date
-----------------------------
2019-07-10-15.05.46.918680...
```

If anymore date has those data where the Initial status was 'A' and then it changed to other status and again came back to 'A' and that date data should be displayed as output.

Comment: Please don't post sample data as an image; the volunteers here can't use it without having to transcribe it (which many of us aren't going to do, when you would have a far easier time doing so). Please post the data as tabular formatted `text`, or as DDL and DML statements. In regards to your attempt, you said it;s not working; why isn't it? Did you get an error, unexpected behaviour, wrong results, something else..? *Also, a note: 2008R8 is completely out of support now; I strongly recommend looking at upgrade paths now, while it still easy to migrate off it.*

Comment: Also, for your sample data, what are the results your after? In addition to describe it, show us the final result you want.

Comment: I mentioned in description.

Comment: Mentioned what? I asked a few of questions in my comments, and i can't see that any of them are mentioned in your question; hence why i asked.

Comment: So reffering to the above screenshot I need data for those Date whose status has changed from A to other like B,C, D etc and again came back to A.

Please help. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: He means show the exact data you expect to get out given the example data, not a description of the output which could be interpreted several ways

Comment: And do not forget to change that image when you do. We can't help you with what we have right now.

Comment: "not working"?   What error do you get?

Comment: @TabAlleman the result I am expecting is not coming, all the dates are coming, I need only those dates whose status was A and then it changed to something else and then get back to A.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
CREATE TABLE #data
(
    Date   DATETIME2,                        
    Status   CHAR(1),              
    Date_Change DATETIME2 
);

INSERT INTO #data(Date, Status, Date_Change) 
VALUES
-- positive example - goes from A to B and back to A
('2019-07-10T15:05:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:05:46.934000'),
('2019-07-10T15:05:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:05:50.272680'),
('2019-07-10T15:05:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:05:50.491680'),  
('2019-07-10T15:05:46.918680','B','2019-07-10T15:05:50.740680'),
('2019-07-10T15:05:46.918680','B','2019-07-10T15:05:50.990680'),
('2019-07-10T15:05:46.918680','A','2019-07-15T10:44:54.386680'),
('2019-07-10T15:05:46.918680','A','2019-07-15T10:44:54.837680'),
('2019-07-10T15:05:46.918680','A','2019-07-15T10:45:28.769680'),
-- a second positive example - goes from A to B and back to A
('2019-07-10T15:06:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:06:46.934000'),
('2019-07-10T15:06:46.918680','B','2019-07-10T15:06:50.740680'),
('2019-07-10T15:06:46.918680','B','2019-07-10T15:06:50.990680'),
('2019-07-10T15:06:46.918680','A','2019-07-15T11:44:54.386680'),
('2019-07-10T15:06:46.918680','A','2019-07-15T11:44:54.837680'),
('2019-07-10T15:06:46.918680','A','2019-07-15T11:45:28.769680'),
-- negative example 1 - always A
('2019-07-10T15:07:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:07:46.934000'),
('2019-07-10T15:07:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:07:50.272680'),
('2019-07-10T15:07:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:07:50.491680'),  
('2019-07-10T15:07:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:07:50.740680'),
-- negative example 2 - goes from A to B but stays there
('2019-07-10T15:08:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:08:46.934000'),
('2019-07-10T15:08:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:08:50.272680'),
('2019-07-10T15:08:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:08:50.491680'),  
('2019-07-10T15:08:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:08:50.740680');

-- so I expect 15:05 and 15:06 to be returned, but not 15:07 and 15:08

WITH ranges AS 
(
    SELECT Date, MIN(Date_Change) MinDate, MAX(Date_Change) MaxDate
    FROM #data 
    WHERE Status = 'A'
    GROUP BY Date
)
SELECT DISTINCT #data.Date
FROM #data
INNER JOIN ranges r ON r.Date = #data.Date
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #data WHERE Date_Change < MaxDate and Date_Change > MinDate AND Status != 'A')
```

Comment: Hi @James Casey , Thanks for the answer but the records which you inserted is like ('2019-07-10T15:05:46.918680','A','2019-07-10T15:05:46.934000') and if you will notice it has 'T' in between the data and my data is not like that. can you please look into it again.

Comment: That's just a standard format I used to insert to my temp table. Your data also had periods in the time instead of colons. I needed to change the format to load into datetime columns. Once they are in the database, they are the same (assuming you actually have date columns and not strings). So long as you leave the colons, you can probably just remove the Ts and I think it will still work

Comment: Sorry for bothering but without T it is not working. with T it is working fine...